# Return of multiple things by a function which is run many times by replicate()

Tags: r

In R, suppose there is a function that return a list of vectors and the function is run with replicate() many times. Then the return from the replicate is a 2D matrix of lists.

I was wondering how to form a vector, which is composed of some particular component in some particular vector of the list returned by each running of the function with replicate()?

For example, how to create a vector from all the last components in the last vectors in all the lists returned by the replicate() on the function myf()? Note that all such components in this example happened to have value 6.

```
> myf<-function(){list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6))}
> out=replicate(4, myf())
> out[3,][[]][2]
Error in out[3, ][[]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
> out[3,]
[[1]]
[1] 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 5 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 6
> out[3,][[1]][2]
[1] 6
> out[3,][[2]][2]
[1] 6
> out[3,][[4]][2]
[1] 6
> out[3,][[3]][2]
[1] 6
```

If you have better way of return multiple things by a function, which is potentially run with replicate, please don't hesitate to reply.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: sounds very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022337/how-to-pick-up-the-last-or-whatever-items-of-all-vectors-inside-a-list -> maybe `sapply(x, tail, n=1)` can be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do this in steps. First look at out:

```
> out
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
[2,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
[3,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
```

A matrix of list of mode numeric, and you apparently only want to work on the rows of that matrix, so let's look at the last elements in each row:

```
> str( apply(out, 2, tail, 1) )
List of 4
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 6
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 6
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 6
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 6
```

So you've got a list of lists. Let's make just a list of vectors:

```
> str( lapply( apply(out, 2, tail, 1), "[[", 1) )
List of 4
 $ : num [1:2] 5 6
 $ : num [1:2] 5 6
 $ : num [1:2] 5 6
 $ : num [1:2] 5 6
```

And get the last element of each:

```
> sapply(lapply( apply(out, 2, tail, 1), "[[", 1), tail, 1)
[1] 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like:

unlist(out)[c(6,12,18,24)]

OR

as.data.frame(out[3,])[2,]

Work for you?